# VueJS: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am getting the 'cannot read property push of undefined' error: here is my vueJs code:

```
data:{
CoIsignedListUID:[]
}
methods:{

fetchCoISigned: function () {
            this.$http.get('/cimsm/public/api/fetchCoIsigned/' + this.conflictofInterest.complaintID).then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                this.$set('CoIsignedList', data);
                data.forEach(function (detail) {
                    this.CoIsignedListUID.push(detail.uID);
                });
            });
```

what am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try this : `this.$data.CoIsignedListUID.push` instead of `this.CoIsignedListUID.push`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this.CoIsignedListUID` is not defined

probably because `this` is not the `this` you think it is

you should do

```
var _this = this
```

outside the function and then

```
_this.CoIsignedListUID.push(detail.uID);
```

Alternatively, you can use ES2015 arrow syntax.

Instead of:

```
.then(function (response) {}
```

Use:

```
.then((response) => {}
```

The 'this' is now available inside the function so no need for creating a new variable. Full details [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the forEach callback is not the vue.js `this`.
you can do this to solve this problem.

```
this.$http.get("...").then(function(response){
    var data = response.data;
    this.$set('CoIsignedList', data);
    var that = this;
    data.forEach(function (detail) {
        that.CoIsignedListUID.push(detail.uID);
    });
});
```